# What can be said about an ideal contracted to a maximal ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A \subseteq B$ be commutative (finitely generated) $k$-algebras, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Let $J$ be an ideal of $B$ and assume that its contraction $I:=J \cap A$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

> **(1)** Is it true that $J$ is a maximal ideal of $B$ or at least a prime ideal of $B$?
>   Probably not?
>
> **(2)** What additional conditions are required in order to guarantee that $J$ is a prime ideal in $B$? For example, integrality of $A \subseteq B$.
>
> **(3)** What if we assume that $J$ is a [radical ideal](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Radical_ideal)?

Relevant questions: [i](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882524/in-an-extension-of-finitely-generated-k-algebras-the-contraction-of-a-maximal) and [ii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107291/the-preimage-of-a-maximal-ideal-is-maximal?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Any hints and coments are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $k \subset k[t]$ and some proper ideal $J \subset k[t]$. Then $J$ cannot contain any non-zero element of $k$ so that the intersection with $k$ is the zero ideal and hence a maximal ideal.

Edit: For an example that is not a field, consider $k[t] \subset k[t,s]$ and the (non-prime) ideal $J = (t,s^2) \subset k[t,s]$. Then $J \cap k[t] = (t) \subset k[t]$ is maximal.

Comment: Thank you very much. You meant, for example, $J=(t^2)$ or more generally $J=(f)$, where $f$ is reducible. Please, what if $A$ is not a field?

Comment: Added another example where $A$ is not a field.

Comment: Nice, thank you! What if $A \subseteq B$ is an algebraic ring extension?

Comment: Perhaps $A=k[x^2,y]$, $B=k[x,y]$, $J=Bx^2+By$ is also a counterexample, since $I=Ax^2+Ay$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, but $J$ is not a prime ideal of $B$ ($J$  is a radical ideal of $B$).

Comment: Perhaps the correct claim is: If $I$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, then $J$ is a radical ideal of $B$?

Comment: What do you mean by an algebraic ring extension? An integral extension? The latter claim is wrong as can be seen by my second example ($J$ contains $s^2$ but not $s$). Its radical is given by $(t,s)$.

Comment: I do not know how to prove (if true) that: $Ax^2+Ay^2 \supseteq (Bx^2+By) \cap A$ (the other inclusion is trivially true).

Comment: By an algebraic extension $A \subseteq B$ I mean that for every element $b \in B$, there exist $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n \in A$ such that $a_nb^n+\cdots+a_1b+a_0=0$. By an integral extension I mean a special case of an algebraic extension, namely, an algebraic extension with $a_n=1$ (for every $b \in B$).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that my latter claim is wrong. I understand your counterexample. Again, your counterexample is for non-algebraic $A \subseteq B$. In my latter claim I meant to further assume that $A \subseteq B$ is algebraic.

Comment: Actually, I guess that my above example of $A=k[x^2,y]$, $B=k[x,y]$, $J=Bx^2+By$ also shows that my latter claim is wrong: $(x^2,y)$ is not radical in $B$. But I am not sure if $Ax^2+Ay=(Bx^2+By) \cap A$.

Comment: Have only checked quickly on the bus now, but seems true to me. By intersecting with $A$ you only take the polynomials whose degree in $x$ is even which would also exactly be the polynomials that you are allowed to use over $A$.

Comment: Thanks you. I wonder if my question can be slightly changed to have a more interesting result. What about requiring separability of $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: Please, what if $\dim(A)=\dim(B)$, with $\dim()$ being the Krull dimension, for example. In your counterexample, $\dim(A)=1, \dim(B)=2$. Thank you!